# Regular expression, ignore specific characters from second group

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression `\[([^]]*)] ([^]]*)` I use it to separate a string like `[text] message to send!` into `text` as a type and `message to send!` as the message, I use it so it's easier to change the type of messages to send. It works really well but I encountered a problem, if the message contains `[ ]` it ends the expression for example: `[text] message to send as a [test] anything after this is ignored!` it would process `text` as group one and only `[text] message to send as a [test` as group two.
How can I make it so the group two is anything after the first `[ ]` is found, ignoring what ever is after and putting it on group two?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/mXDReg/2

Comment: you can do this right \\[(.*)\\] (.*) \\[.*\\] ? group1 will be the type and group2 the actual message

Comment: @karthick Doesn't work, it doesn't even include the second [] in the message. :/

Comment: Can you give a clear example of expected output? I thought you want only this as output "message to send as a"

Comment: @karthick The first text inside the first bracket needs to be group 1, anything else that comes after needs to be group two. The output I want for the group two is the whole thing "message to send as a [test] anything after this is ignored!". But I can't get it to work because if there is brackets in it, it stops.

Comment: so this then anything after the first group \\[([^]]*)](.*)

Comment: @karthick Yes! That worked, thank you! Post it as an answer and I'll choose it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already matching the first group if all you want to do is match the rest then simply change the regex from

```
\[([^]]*)] ([^]]*)
```

to

```
\[([^]]*)](.*)
```